# Capybara-webkit throws Can't find variable: $

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara-webkit, wysihtml5

I'm trying to fill a [wysihmlt5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5) textarea with [Capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) (not sure if there is another way):

```
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
page.execute_script %Q{ $('#wysihtml5-textarea').data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue('Lorem ipsum') }
```

But I get thsi error:

```
undefined|0|ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
FQFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)

Failure/Error: page.execute_script %Q{ $('#wysihtml5-textarea').data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue('Lorem ipsum') }
     Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:
       Javascript failed to execute
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Seems jQuery is not loaded?

Comment: @sphairHow to load jQuery in Rspec?

Comment: Sorry, don't know :) Haven't used Rspec myself..

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only thing you're using jQuery for, you could try

```
document.getElementById('wysihtml5-textarea');
```